# Show custom navigation on top of inappbrowser Phonegap webview app

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova, phonegap

I load a webpage via the inappbrowser plugin for my Phonegap app.
The app shows a website and a webshop which are both accessible from the web as well.
I cannot add a button 'go back to app' (this wouldn't make sense when visiting the site from PC). So I want a custom navigation (I prefer bootstrap) in the phonegap app so I can navigate between multiple different websites.

Unfortunately the navigation gets hidden by the inappbrowser. Is there a way to show the app html navigation on top of the inappbrowser?

Thanks a lot!

adding absolute position, z-index 999999 and display block with css didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you do could this is inject the button into your webpage by generating it in your Cordova app Webview:

```
var inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("http://www.mypage.com", "_blank");

inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function(e) {
    inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ 
        code: '\
            var body = document.querySelector("body");\
            var button = document.createElement("div");\
            button.innerHTML = "Return to app";\
            button.classList.add("close_button");\
            button.onclick = function() {\
                webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify({action: "closeIAB"}));\
            };\
            body.appendChild(button);\
        '
    });
});
```

You'd then add a listener for the message that's posted when the button is click which closes the inappbrowser:

```
inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener("message", function (params){
    if(params.data.action === "closeIAB"){
        inAppBrowserRef.close();
    }
});
```

You could also inject the styling of the button from within your Cordova app:

```
inAppBrowserRef.insertCSS({
    "code": "\
        .close_button {\
            position: fixed;\
            bottom: 0;\
            z-index: 500;\
            width: 100%;\
            background: white;\
            color: black;\
            padding: 10px;\
            font-size: 20px;\
        }"
});
```

Or if you prefer, add the button styling to the CSS in your webpage (if it's under your control).

Similarly, if you don't like the idea of creating the button HTML dynamically, you could include it as part of your webpage but hide it by default unless a particular class is injected by the app:

```
inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function(e) {
    inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ 
        code: '\
            var body = document.querySelector("body");\
            body.classList.add("is_app");\
        '
    });
});
```

And in your website CSS:

```
body:not(.is_app) .close_button{
    display: none;
}
```

Note that the emulation of the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) that has been added to [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) for Android & iOS by [this PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/362) is not yet in the [latest release version on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) (`v3.0.0`) so you'll need to install the plugin directly off the Github master branch (`v3.1.0-dev`):

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this long time ago another way. The in app browser opened a website with a additional GET parameter, so the website knows it's opened inside the app. Then in the website I generated a special button, with href containing a custom scheme and some command. (E.g.  myapp://close-browser)

Then I configured the app to capture the custom url by using regular app scheme configuration. Once I captured the command in javascript, I closed the in app browser using it's API.